# Is this the sufficient condition for not having infinitely small modes in a distribution?

Tags: distributions, mode

I was reading the paper *Optimal Throughput and Delay in Delay-tolerant Networks with Ballistic Mobility* (http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2500432), and found the following proposition (page 305):

"(We require that) if $s$ has a probability bounded away from $0$ of exceeding a certain threshold $\overline{s}$, then it has probability density at least $\Omega{(\frac{1}{\overline{s}})}$ over an open interval of speeds of size $\Omega{(\overline{s})}$ containing $\overline{s}$ (this condition essentially prohibits node speeds from having infinitely small modes)."

In this context, $s$ is a random variable representing node speeds with support in $[0,1]$ and having some distribution with the above property. My question is, why is this a sufficient condition to guarantee that the distribution will not have infinitely small modes? If someone could provide the explanation or point to some relevant theory, it would be really helpful.